# Region and Language settings crash

Tags: 14.04, gnome, language-support, ubuntu-gnome, input-language

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. I recently installed 14.04 Gnome on an Asus Chromebook. All settings have been working fine but the Region and Language settings keep crashing. There is no specific error number but it says:

> [region]: gnome-control-center.real crashed with SIGSEGV in g_sequence_sort_changed_iter()

I want to be able to have English and a few other languages (Bulgarian, Icelandic, Swedish, Danish) as input languages.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This appears to be a [gnome-control-center bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center).

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling and reading around a bit, I found a solution. It turned out the locale file was empty (the problem was the `region`, rather than the `language` part), so I edited it:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/locale
```

and added this to the file:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

That's all.